# Which is the basis for the space?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

We have the following linear system of equations:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1& 2\\ 3 & 4 & 6\\ 2 & 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{b}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 7\\ 3\end{pmatrix}$

I want to solve the homogeneous and the inhomogeneous system, and to find a basis for the space of the solutions of the homogeneous system.

I have found that $Ax=0 \Rightarrow x=0$. Wihch is the  a basis for the space of the solutions of the homogeneous system?

Comment: The basis is the empty set.  The solution space is $0$-dimensional, since there is a unique solution.

Comment: So, the dimension of the solution space is equal to the number of solutions? At an other system I found that the solution is $$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=(-2x_2, x_2, 0, 0)=x_2(-2,1,0,0), \ x_2\in \mathbb{R}.$$ Which is in this case the basis? The $\{(-2,1,0,0)\}$ ? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: The dimension of the solution space (to the homogeneous problem) is the number of **linearly independent solutions**.  But yes, that's right.

Comment: And is the basis $\{-2,1,0,0)\}$ unique? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: No, the basis isn't unique.  We could also take $\{(2,-1,0,0)\}$, or $\{-20,10,0,0\}$.

Comment: In most cases, bases are not unique (hence avoid the term "the basis"). In the example you provided $(-2,1,0,0)$ constitutes a possible basis for the solution space, however you can easily see that any multiple could be selected as its basis. For example $(-4,2,0,0)$ is also a basis. Hope this helps clarifying some stuff.

Comment: Ah ok... But the empty set at the first system is the only basis, or not? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Ah ok... But the empty set at the first system is the only basis, or not? @Litteul

Comment: Yes, the empty set is the only basis of the $0$-dimensional space.

Comment: I see...  You said that the dimension of the solution space (to the **homogeneous problem**) is the number of linearly independent solutions. Does this only hold in the case of an homogeneous problem? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: The solution space to the non-homogeneous problem is not a linear subspace (it is instead an *affine* subspace), so we don't generally talk about its dimension or basis directly.

Comment: Ah ok... At the first case, where the solution s $(0,0,0)$... Why isn't $(0,0,0)$ one linearly independent solution, and so the dimension equal to $1$ ?  I got stuck right now... @Omnomnomnom